# How to disable GZipContent in Cloud Endpoints builder in Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-endpoints

I want to disable GZipContent for a Google Cloud Endpoints class so that a POST can work on the local development server.

The latest GPE release generates this endpoint builder:

```
public static final class Builder extends AbstractGoogleJsonClient.Builder {
    public Builder(HttpTransport transport, JsonFactory jsonFactory,
        HttpRequestInitializer httpRequestInitializer) {
      super(
          transport,
          jsonFactory,
          ...);
    }
```

and Google documentation recommends using it like this:

```
Myendpoint.Builder endpointBuilder = new Myendpoint.Builder(
                    AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                    new GsonFactory(),
                    credential);
```

Does anyone know how to disable GZipContent for the endpoint?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use:

```
builder.setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new TictactoeRequestInitializer() {
     protected void initializeTictactoeRequest(TictactoeRequest<?> request) {
         request.setDisableGZipContent(true);
     }
   });
```

Replace `TictactoeRequest` with the appropriate class for your application.

Comment: Thanks Dan! That looks just right (I noticed the control in the xxxxxRequestInitializer but wasn't sure how to use it).  I'll test it later when I'm done with my day-job and accept the answer then.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% why Dan's answer didn't work for me, but this [GitHub project's code](https://github.com/bradabrams/stopwatchio13/blob/master/stopwatch-Endpoints/src/main/java/com/geekyouup/android/ustopwatch/CloudEndpointUtils.java) solved it for me.

```
/*
 * TODO: Need to change this to 'true' if you're running your backend locally using
 * the DevAppServer. See
 * http://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/cloud_endpoints for more
 * information.
 */
protected static final boolean LOCAL_ANDROID_RUN = false;

/*
 * The root URL of where your DevAppServer is running (if you're running the
 * DevAppServer locally).
 */
protected static final String LOCAL_APP_ENGINE_SERVER_URL = "http://localhost:8080/";

/*
 * The root URL of where your DevAppServer is running when it's being
 * accessed via the Android emulator (if you're running the DevAppServer
 * locally). In this case, you're running behind Android's virtual router.
 * See
 * http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses
 * for more information.
 */
protected static final String LOCAL_APP_ENGINE_SERVER_URL_FOR_ANDROID = "http://10.0.2.2:8080";

/**
 * Updates the Google client builder to connect the appropriate server based
 * on whether LOCAL_ANDROID_RUN is true or false.
 *
 * @param builder Google client builder
 * @return same Google client builder
 */
public static <B extends AbstractGoogleClient.Builder> B updateBuilder(
        B builder) {
    if (LOCAL_ANDROID_RUN) {
        builder.setRootUrl(LOCAL_APP_ENGINE_SERVER_URL_FOR_ANDROID
                + "/_ah/api/");
    }

    // only enable GZip when connecting to remote server
    final boolean enableGZip = builder.getRootUrl().startsWith("https:");

    builder.setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new GoogleClientRequestInitializer() {
        public void initialize(AbstractGoogleClientRequest<?> request)
                throws IOException {
            if (!enableGZip) {
                request.setDisableGZipContent(true);
            }
        }
    });

    return builder;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those that are Googling for the error I saw, it was java.io.EOFException, but only in the development server.  Here's how I was able to fix this, using the example stated in the OP's question:

```
Myendpoint myendpointClient = new Myendpoint.Builder(
                AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                new GsonFactory(),
                credential).build();
EndpointService svcCall = myendpointClient.endpointService("firstArg");
// Note, I didn't call "execute()", as normal!
svcCall.setDisableGZipContent(true);
// This is also a handy place to set http headers, etc
svcCall.getRequestHeaders().set("x-oddballhdr","OddballValue");
// It's now time to call execute()
svcCall.execute();
```

That may be a bit simpler than the other helpful answers.